# merge two dataframe Python with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I trying to concat in python the following datasets:

df1:

```
class,     cvss,  cwe,  description,  line,  reccomandation,   vul_id
a.class    cvss1    cwe1,   desc1,    l1,        rec1,          vul1
```

df2:

```
Title,NTimes,Synopsis,Description,Solution,Risk Factor,CVSS Temporal Score
tit1, nt1     syn1         desc2  sol1      risk1         cvss2
tit2, nt2     syn2         desc3  sol2     risk2          cvss3
```

I want to append the information of the columns df1.cwe,df1.description, df1.cvss with df2.Title, df2.Description and df2.CVSS Temporal Score to obtains the following situation:

```
class,   line,reccomandation,vul_id,Title,NTimes,Synopsis,Description,Solution,Risk Factor,CVSS Temporal Score
a.class  l1   rec1           vul1   cwe1,                  desc1                            cvss1     
                                    tit1   nt1     syn1    desc2      sol1      risk1       cvss2
                                    tit2   nt2     syn2    desc3      sol2      risk2       cvss3
```

I have tried using merge but without success using the follow code:

```
 res= pd.merge(df1,df2 left_on=['cwe','description','cvss'],right_on=['Title','Description','CVSS Temporal Score'])
```

Comment: *I have tried using both merge and concat* provide your code and explain how it failed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following approach  :

```
#create new empty data frame 
df = pd.DataFrame()

#add the columns from df1 to df
df['cwe']=df1['cwe']
#add the rest of the columns from df1 to df as above

#add the columns from df2 to df
df['title']=df1['title']
#add the rest of the columns from df2 to df as above

#view the new dataframe
df
```

Comment: sorry but this solution don't answer to the post

Comment: if you need to merge the columns from different data frames this will work. that's what you've mentioned in the description! isn't it?